# Extension is not loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have installed extension successfully. The installed module is showing in "`System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`" in admin page. But it seems the module is not loaded.

The module should be shown in admin page and site. Anyway I have tested this module in localhost and it work fine. But not in share host(live host).

I have done all of this but no luck

> 1. clear cache
> 2. Log out and in
> 3. disable magento compilation
> 4. Do a chmod -R 777 on the root of your magento installation

Can someone suggest me how can I troubleshooting this situation?

Thanks

Here is the module's xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jayje_Rma>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Jayje_Rma>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: can you put ...module xml file

Comment: have you use any cache extension

Comment: I didn't install any cache extension

Comment: delete all file from var/cache

Comment: done but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the case that your extension works on a local (windows) system, but not on a remote (linux) system? If yes carefully check if your extension filenames match the magento standard upper/lower case rules (windows does not care while linux does).

Comment: OMG you r right. It is exactly what you said.